# How many different three-digit numbers contain both the digit $2$ and the digit $6$?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

> How many different three-digit numbers contain both the digit $2$ and the digit $6$?

There are six possible permutations: $$
\overline{26x},\ \overline{62x},\ \overline{2x6},\ \overline{6x2},\ \overline{x26},\ \overline{x62}.
$$

In the first four groups $x$ can be any number in $[0,9]$, in the two last groups $x$ can be any number in range $[1,9]$. So
$$
4 \times 10 + 2 \times 9 = 58.
$$
However, the right answer is $52$. Could you, please, point out the mistake in the reasoning?

Comment: Where could you have double counted?

Comment: Consider the number $266$. How many times is it counted in your reasoning?

Comment: Another option, rather than brute forcing it like you did (*after correcting for overcounting*) is to count the number of three-digit numbers which don't contain a $2$, *or* don't contain a $6$ (*or don't contain either*), which can be done with relatively little stress using inclusion-exclusion.  This would be the preferred approach for the generalization.  If you were doing it for the same question but ten-digit numbers instead, you do *NOT* want to do it the way you did here.  It would take forever.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your method overcounts the numbers $266(26x;2x6),622(62x;6x2),262(26x;x62),626(62x;x26),662(6x2;x62),226(x26;2x6)$

*Another approach to this problem*

Case 1 : The 3 digit number contains all distinct digits

Numbers formed= $\binom {8}{1}.3!$

But we also count in this the numbers which start with 0 so we subtract them.

Numbers in this case hence=$\binom {8}{1}3!-2!=46$

Case 2: The 3 digit number contains exactly 2 digits same.

The two digits can be $2$ or $6$

Hence numbers in this case = $\binom {2}{1}\cdot \frac {3!}{2!}=6$

Hence total numbers required =$46+6=52$

Answer (score 2):

You should also take into account the repetition of a number. The following numbers are repeated:

$226({x26\text{ and }2x6})$

$262(26x\text{ and }x62)$

$266(26x\text{ and }2x6)$

$622(62x\text{ and }6x2)$

$626(62x\text{ and }x26)$

$662(6x2\text{ and }x62)$

So after subtracting the number of repeated numbers (i.e. $6$) from $58$, we get $52$.

A genuine approach to this problem is given in the other answer of Manthanein.

Comment: Grammar point:  You meant repetition of a number.